# Mongodb Motor driver for Windows

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, tornado-motor

Question about Motor https://github.com/mongodb/motor

README says "Unix, including Mac OS X. Windows is not supported."

I run python 3.5 with motor 1.0 on Windows and it seems works good.

insert, update, delete, find, reindex operations, capped collections and tailable cursor works fine with `asyncio`.

**What is not supported on Windows?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm Motor's author. Here's what's not supported with Motor and Windows:

- I don't test Motor on Windows.
- Tornado doesn't officially support Windows--it's not designed for scalability there--so when you use Motor with Tornado on Windows you can't expect production-level performance.

You might be fine on Windows, particularly with the asyncio integration, since asyncio *is* officially supported on Windows. But be aware that I've made no effort to ensure Motor is correct, scalable, or fast on Windows.

I've updated Motor's "requirements" document with this info:

https://github.com/mongodb/motor/blob/master/doc/requirements.rst#not-supported